# Use a requested value from a server to create an instance of a class

Tags: angular, observable

I want to create class which contains my custom classes.

Here my class is a **customer** and the custom class which it contains is **Country**.

For Countries I have the following class:

```
export class Country {
    constructor(public shortcut: string, public description: string) { }
}
```

I get a list from Countries from a **country service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Country } from './country';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

  countries: Country[];

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getCountries().subscribe();
   }

  getCountries(): Observable<any> {
    if(this.countries != null) {
      return Observable.of(this.countries)
    } else {
      return this.http.get(`http://my-json-server.typicode.com/kolomu/CustomerDemoApp/countries`, { method: 'Get'})
      .map( (response) => response.json() )
      .map( (countries) => this.countries = countries)
    }
  }

  getDescription(shortcut: string): Observable<string> {
    if(this.countries != null) {
      let tempCountry = this.countries.find( (e) => e.shortcut == shortcut);
      return Observable.of(tempCountry.description);
    } else {
      this.getCountries().subscribe(
        (countries) => {
          let tempCountry = this.countries.find( (e) => e.shortcut == shortcut);
          return Observable.of(tempCountry.description);
        }
      );
    }

  }

}
```

My initial thought was that I have a country service which always contains the country description and country shortcuts for easy access. E.g. calling getDescription(countryShortcut) to get the Description of the provided country shortcut. However as I learned from Observable such things are not possible the way I thought.

To get the country description I need a call like this:

```
this.countryService.getDescription.subscribe(
  countryDescription => // Here I have the return value from country description
)
```

My problem is that somehow the wording and method call doesnt make sense anymore.

See the Customer class below how I create a country inside a getDescription call...

```
import { AppInjector } from './app-injector';
import { Country } from './country';
import { CountryService } from './country.service';

export class Customer {

    public country: Country;
    public countryService: CountryService;

    constructor(public name: string, public countryShortcut: string){
        this.countryService = AppInjector.get(CountryService);


        this.countryService.getDescription(countryShortcut).subscribe(
            countryDescription => {
                return new Country(countryShortcut, countryDescription)
            } 
        )

    }


}
```

Where is my thinking mistake? Maybe the complete process of creating a customer with my own country instance is wrong? Any help is gladly appreciated.

Also below is the github repo of the project.
https://github.com/kolomu/CustomerDemoApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some things.

1. Use httpClient, NOT http. so, you not need use response.json()
2. Use Observable< any[] > if you want to subscribe to a observable that return an array
   3.-map change the response. If you want to do something with the response use do, so

L

```
getCountries(): Observable<any[]> { //<--return an array
    if(this.countries != null) {
      return Observable.of(this.countries);
    } else {
      return this.http.get(`http://my-json-server.typicode.com/kolomu/CustomerDemoApp/countries`)  //we don't need json because we use httpClient
                        //If use "get" not put "method get"
    .do((result)=>this.countries=result); //use "do" to do something more with the response. do NOT change the response
}
```

3. You don't subscribe in your method getDescription. You use "map" to change the response. or switchMap

L

```
getDescription(shortcut: string): Observable<string> {
    if(this.countries != null) {
      let tempCountry = this.countries.find( (e) => e.shortcut == shortcut);
      return Observable.of(tempCountry.description);
    } else {
      this.getCountries().map( //If not work try switchMap instead map
        (countries) => {
          let tempCountry = this.countries.find( (e) => e.shortcut == shortcut);
          return tempCountry.description; //not Observable.of
        }
      );
    }
```

4. Your class must be private the arguments in the constructor
5. in your customer must be

L

```
this.country=new Country(...)
```

6. In my opinion, you don't need class, just interfaces, (you have not method in a class)